# is it true that weight loss for people who have been quite over-weight for a long time will only result in loose skin?

Tags: weight-loss, skin

I heard that people who have been over-weight for a while have 'permanently' stretched their skin, and for that reason weight loss will only result in loose skin (appearance wise).

Doesn't age have something to do with this (if your still young, it tightens up, right?)?

Can someone please set me straight about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that significant fat loss will result in some loose skin, most (or all) of which should tighten up over time.

But only people who see you naked will see the loose skin. Everyone else will see a thinner person. So the answer is no - weight loss will NOT "only" result in loose skin appearance wise.

I lost 70+ pounds at age 32. I have fully visible abs and am at about 10% body fat. When I do pushups, I have a tiny bit of loose skin that hangs down off my belly that I'm pretty sure wouldn't be there had I never been so heavy, and that I'm fairly certain will never go away. But if you saw me shirtless at the pool, you'd never know it was there. Here's [a pic of me from a few months ago](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7158/6507668403_920ae25597.jpg) - you tell me: did my fat loss "only" result in loose skin?

Comment: You're right! I can't see any visible loose skin in either pixel!

Comment: Dude, learn to upload picutres in a viewable size.

Comment: @RandomDuck.NET you can remove the `_s` from the end of the link to see higher res

Comment: @FranzKafka CC.

Answer (score 7):

[Skin is living tissue](http://getfitguy.quickanddirtytips.com/how-to-tighten-loose-skin-after-weight-loss.aspx), and the speed at which it shrinks to it's new level of needed tightness depends on how fast you can make new skin.  In short, the older you are the longer it takes for your skin to tighten up.

There does seem to be some evidence that the types of food you eat can speed up the results a bit, such as collagen.